# Search value in List<T> inside another List<T>

Tags: c#, linq

i have class strucur something like this

```
List<MainCat> AllCat;

public class MainCat
{
    public string id { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }
    public List<subcat> subcat { get; set; }
}

public class subcat
{
    public string id { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }
    public List<subsubcat> subsubcat { get; set; }
}

public class subsubcat
{
    public string id { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }
}
```

i want to get **name** by **id**,
for example i know the id is **69**

i want get output like this

MainCat.name > subcat.name > subsubcat.name (if **69** found in subsubcat)

MainCat.name > subcat.name (if **69** found in subcat)

MainCat.name (if **69** found in MainCat)

Comment: What if the id is in multiple or all of them? By name would make more sense, but both ways, you can just do a recursive search by going through them, or make some kind of mapping table.

Comment: I'm sure you tried something. Please show your efforts so wee can see where *specifically* you need help. Currently it's not clear what you're asking.

Comment: i am sorry if my question is not clear enough..  ID is unique..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I've understood your requirement properly, this is a case where the query syntax can work wonders:

```
IEnumerable<string> MyFunc(IEnumerable<MainCat> mainCategories, string idToMatch)
{
  return (from main in mainCategories
          where main.id == idToMatch
          select main.name)
    .Concat(from main in mainCategories
            from sub in main.subcat
            where sub.id == idToMatch
            select string.Format("{0} > {1}", main.name, sub.name))
    .Concat(from main in mainCategories
            from sub in main.subcat
            from subsub in sub.subsubcat
            where subsub.id == idToMatch
            select string.Format("{0} > {1} > {2}", main.name, sub.name, subsub.name));
}
```

If you're only interested in the first match, this can be called like

```
string resultName = MyFunc(AllCat, "69").FirstOrDefault();
```

Because the query uses deferred execution, this will avoid calling the more complex queries if a match is found in the main category.

It is also possible to use the `SelectMany` function with the function call syntax, however, it gets much harder to follow e.g. the following is how I re-wrote the contents of the second `.Concat(...)` call in order to illustrate:

```
mainCategories.SelectMany(main => main.subcat, (main, sub) => new { Main = main, Sub = sub })
              .SelectMany(pair => pair.Sub.subsubcat, (pair, subsub) => new { Main = pair.Main, Sub = pair.Sub, SubSub = subsub})
              .Where(triplet => triplet.SubSub.id == idToMatch)
              .Select(triplet => string.Format("{0} > {1} > {2}", triplet.Main, triplet.Sub, triplet.SubSub));
```

As I understand it, the query syntax compiles to something very similar to this behind the scenes.

---

Update after answer accepted, and I came back to look at my code again:

Another possibility would be to add an interface to all 3 classes (or unify them into a single class or derive from a common base class depending on real use case).

This allows a recursive implementation that can search to arbitrary depth (below are 2 different Linq-based implementations depending on whether you have a preference for one or other syntax):

```
public interface ITreeCat
{
  string id { get; }
  string name { get; }
  IEnumerable<ITreeCat> subcat { get; }
}

// add explicit interface implemetantion to existing 3 classes
// e.g.
// IEnumerable<ITreeCat> ITreeCat.subcat { get { return subsubcat; } }
// IEnumerable<ITreeCat> ITreeCat.subcat { get { return Enumerable.Empty<ITreeCat>(); } }

IEnumerable<string> MyFunc(IEnumerable<ITreeCat> categories, string idToMatch, string prefix = "")
{
  return (from cat in categories
          where cat.id == idToMatch
          select prefix + cat.name)
    .Concat(from cat in categories
            from recursiveResult in MyFunc(cat.subcat, idToMatch, prefix + cat.name + " > ")
            select recursiveResult);
}

IEnumerable<string> MyFunc2(IEnumerable<ITreeCat> categories, string idToMatch, string prefix = "")
{
  return categories.Where(cat => cat.id == idToMatch)
                   .Select(cat => prefix + cat.name)
                   .Concat(categories.SelectMany(cat => MyFunc2(cat.subcat, idToMatch, prefix + cat.name + " > ")));
}
```

This has the advantage that it continues to work if you later add a subsubsubcat etc.

All of the above code examples use a breadth-first search, and repeatedly enumerate the "parent" categories each time they go one level deeper.

In some applications a depth-first search may be a better choice, as each list is only enumerated once, in which case it's much easier to use `foreach` rather than Linq. Again, a recursive version is more concise than 3 nested loops with different classes:

```
IEnumerable<string> MyFuncDepthFirst(IEnumerable<ITreeCat> categories, string idToMatch)
{
  foreach(var cat in categories)
  {
    if (cat.id == idToMatch)
      yield return cat.name;
    foreach (var subResult in MyFuncDepthFirst(cat.subcat, idToMatch))
      yield return string.Format("{0} > {1}", cat.name, subResult);
  }
}
```

This still assumes that multiple matches can occur. If we're just after the first match, then there's no need to use an iterator block at all, and the above function can be modified to return a simple string:

```
string FirstMatchingIdDepthFirst(IEnumerable<ITreeCat> categories, string idToMatch)
{
  foreach(var cat in categories)
  {
    if (cat.id == idToMatch)
      return cat.name;
    string subResult = FirstMatchingIdDepthFirst(cat.subcat, idToMatch);
    if(subResult != null)
      return string.Format("{0} > {1}", cat.name, subResult);
  }
  return null;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var list = this.AllCat.Where(t=>t.subcat.Any(s=> subsubcat.contains(s));
```

Comment: This doesn't fulfill the requirements. It only searches inside subsubcat. But not in subcat or MainCat

Answer (score 0):

You can go for a method like below

```
public static Type Find(string id, MainCat m)
{
    if (m.id.Equals(id))
    {
        return m.GetType();
    }
    if (m.subcat.Any(a => a.id.Equals(id)))
    {
        return typeof(subcat);
    }
    if (m.subcat.Any(a => a.subsubcat.Any(b => b.id.Equals(id))))
    {
        return typeof(subsubcat);
    }
    return null;
}
```

and perform the search. Find the gist, https://gist.github.com/IshamMohamed/33d75064789d77d88404b8ffc9a17e94

In this way you can increase the number of inner lists (eg: `subsubsubcat`)